# 80s-90s anime with a blonde main character whose mother dies

Tags: jeanie-with-the-light-brown-hair

I am looking for an old TV-series.
As far as I remember there were different specific characters and a plot in something like a farm.
The main-character was a blonde and blue-eyes girl, who had a mother who died (I think due to a disease) and she told her, that when someone dies, they turn into a star.
The father was a doctor I think, he had, if I remember correctly, a mustache and brown hair.
Then there was of course the mother, she had long blond hair too, like her daughter.
The daughter would often wear pink dresses.

Another boy, who has brown hair and probably worked on the farm along side with another black boy who worked at the farm with his father.

The boy with the brown hair would later go search for her, find her in something like a foster home, lead by a nun and something like a butler, who raise children, and the main-character helps them.

The brown-haired boy asks her if she wants to marry her, but she doesn't want to and hides behind a door.

This is all I can remember, I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like [**Jeanie with the Light Brown Hair**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeanie_with_the_Light_Brown_Hair_(anime))

[image: pic]

> The story begins in a small town in Pennsylvania in 1838. Jeanie MacDowell is a cheerful and beautiful girl with light brown hair (although this could be perceived as being blonde hair). Jeanie enjoys playing the piano and loves taking piano lessons from her mother.
>
> Steven, a good harmonica player, and Bill, a boy who is very good at playing the banjo, are great friends of Jeanie's. They enjoy playing music together like a small band.
>
> However, Jeanie's happy life changes dramatically after her mother suddenly passes away.
>
> Experiencing many difficulties and learning the importance of life, she decides to devote her life to helping many people suffering from illness.
>
> The series is a love story about the relationship between Steven and Jeanie

Comment: Oh, magnificent! Thank you very much! That is exactly the story, I can tell by just looking at the picture.